# Custom JQuery code does not load

Tags: views, javascript

Iam trying to call custom JQuery code but its just not working

new HtmlCommand() and InvokeCommand(method:css) is just working fine, just my custom script is not executed:

Controller:

```
    <?php
    /** * @file * Contains Drupal\ajax_example\AjaxExampleForm */

    namespace Drupal\ajax_example\Form;

    use Drupal\ajax_example\Ajax\AjaxExampleCommand; use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse; 
    use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CommandInterface; 
    use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ChangedCommand; 
    use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CssCommand; 
    use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand; 
    use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand; 
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase; 
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

    class AjaxExampleForm extends FormBase{

    /**
     * @param array $form
     * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value' => 'Login',
            '#attached' => array(
              'library' => array(
                'ajax_example/ajaxCustom','core/jquery')),
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'Drupal\ajax_example\Form\AjaxExampleForm::ajaxCallOwn',
                'event' => 'click',
                'progress' => array(
                    'type' => 'throbber',
                    'message' => 'ajaxOwn',
                ),
        ));
    }

public function ajaxCallOwn(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();

    //$ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#edit-user-name2--description', "changedDessrition!!!!"));

    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL,'changeDescription'));
    return $ajax_response;
  }
```

Command:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains Drupal\ajax_example\Ajax\AjaxExampleCommand
 */

namespace Drupal\ajax_example\Ajax;

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CommandInterface;

class AjaxExampleCommand implements CommandInterface{

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  protected $blub;
  // Constructs a SystemBlubCommand object.

  /**
   * Constructs an SlideDownCommand object.
   * @param string $blub
   */

  public function __construct() {
    $this->blub = "changed!!!!";
  }

  public function render() {
    return array(
      'command' => 'changeDescription',
      'method' => NULL,
      'blub' => $this->blub,
    );
  }
}
```

ajaxCustom.js

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

    /**
     * Command to Slide Down page elements before removing them.
     *
     * @param {Drupal.Ajax} [ajax]
     * @param {object} response
     * @param {string} response.blub
     * @param {number} [status]
     */

    Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.changeDescription = function (ajax, response, status) {

        alert("asdfasdgf");
        $("#edit-user-name--description").remove();
        $("#edit-user-name--description").html(response.blub);

    };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

ajax_example.libraries.yml:

```
ajax_example:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/ajaxCustom.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/jquery
```

Tried so many things like : [this](https://api.drupal.org/comment/62911#comment-62911) 
with no success

This is the error I get in the Browser:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Drupal.AjaxCommands.invoke (ajax.js?v=8.4.4:569)
    at Drupal.Ajax.success (ajax.js?v=8.4.4:407)
    at Object.success (ajax.js?v=8.4.4:222)
    at Object.t.success (jquery.form.min.js?v=3.51:11)
    at i (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:4)
invoke @ ajax.js?v=8.4.4:569
Drupal.Ajax.success @ ajax.js?v=8.4.4:407
success @ ajax.js?v=8.4.4:222
t.success @ jquery.form.min.js?v=3.51:11
i @ jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:2
A @ jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:4
e.fn.ajaxSubmit @ jquery.form.min.js?v=3.51:11
Drupal.Ajax.eventResponse @ ajax.js?v=8.4.4:316
(anonymous) @ ajax.js?v=8.4.4:255
dispatch @ jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1:3
```

If I use InvokeCommand error in recent logs:

```
Deprecated function: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Drupal\ajax_example\Form\AjaxExampleForm2::ajaxCallOwn() should not be called statically in Drupal\Core\Form\FormAjaxResponseBuilder->buildResponse() (line 69 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormAjaxResponseBuilder.php) #0
```

Comment: `InvokeCommand` invokes a jQuery function on the elements, so you'd need `$.fn.changeDescription = function(data) { alert(data); };`. Otherwise you should use the command you've created: `$ajax_response->addCommand(new AjaxExampleCommand());`

Comment: Clive beat me to it. Yes you want the PHP class command you made, not InvokeCommand that’s for arbitrary JS function calls.

Comment: Thanks for your anser, but I still get the error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
Even in another Controller where new  AppendCommand works fine.
And I alway do: drush cc drush and drush cr
This really drives me nuts since 3 days

Comment: Why is method null and what is “blub”? You can compare it here to a module I wrote: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sweetalert/tree

Comment: Should be `'library' => array('module_name/library_name')),` So in your case, since the library name is the same as the module name, `'library' => array('ajax_example/ajax_example')),`

Comment: You’re mixing up concepts here and changing code in the original question making it harder to follow. You can’t point an Ajax event on a form item at a command directly, you can only instantiate and return them as part of an AjaxResponse inside of an Ajax callback within a form.

Comment: Plus your attachments are wrong too

Comment: Again if you want to use your AjaxExampleCommand, you need to create it and return it in the AjaxRepsonse. You DONT need InvokeCommand, that is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [*No Sssweat*](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/27710/no-sssweat), that was the problem!

I thought it should be:

```
'library' => array('module_name/nameOfJSFile'));
```

Thanks to Kevin as well, your module sweetalert gave me the right hint.